# Extract domain from a link in Python and using SQL

Tags: python, sql, db2

I have a database to which I am connecting to using Python and running the sql statements in the following way .

```
import ibm_db
conn = ibm_db.connect("DATABASE=ABCD;HOSTNAME=dsomehostname.net;PORT=50001;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=User1_id;PWD=Password; Security = SSL; ConnectTimeout = 30; sslConnection=TRUE","","")
connState = ibm_db.active(conn)
print(connState)
import ibm_db_dbi
# con = ibm_db_dbi.Connection(conn)

sql = "SELECT emails from Database1.Table1 WHERE TIMESTAMP>'2020-08-20' GROUP BY emails; "
stmt = ibm_db.exec_immediate(conn, sql)
dictionary = ibm_db.fetch_both(stmt)
```

It is giving me emails in the following way :

```
**https://abc**.ind.analytics.google.com/bs/?perspective=story
**https://abc**.ind.analytics.google.com/bs/
**https://tmb**.ind.analytics.google.com/bs/?perspective=ca-modeller
**https://fgt**.ind.analytics.google.com/bs/?perspective=explore
(null)
**https://abc**.ind.analytics.google.com/bs/?perspective=home
(null)
**https://col**.ind.analytics.google.com/bs/?perspective=classicviewer
**https://prod**.ind.analytics.google.com/bs/
(null)
**https://fcv**.ind.analytics.google.com/bs/?perspective=home
**https://prod**.health-analytics.something-else.com/bs/
(null)
**https://fcv**.health-analytics.something-else?perspective=home
```

I only want the bold part. i.e. I only want the part before "ind.analytics.google.com/bs/......"  AND NOT before "health-analytics.something-else.com/bs/...:

```
https://abc
 https://tmb
 https://fgt
```

Is there a way I can include regex into this and fire the query. It will be great if someone can help me out with that.

Comment: Try a regex similar to this `select regexp_extract(emails, '^.*(?=(\.ind\.analytics\.google\.com))' ) from ...`  (where emails is your column-name)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the dictionary and collect the data you want into a list.

```
emailList = []
for email in dictionary:
    domain = email.split('.')[0] // as the domain is the first element
    emailList.append(domain)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply . I am specifically looking for regex as there might be emails like :

**https://fgt**.abc.database.com
(null)
**https://abc**.abc.database.com?perspective=home